# Unity2D, instantiated objects keep shaking

Tags: c#, gameobject, unity-game-engine

I am making a boss for my 2D platform game, and I met a problem at instantiating smaller bosses when the big boss die. So I have a script called BossHealthManager, and in it when the boss health reached <= 0, it will instantiate 2 smaller bosses. However, when kill the big boss and instantiated the 2 smaller bosses, they kept shaking  on the spot and never move. All the bosses are attached with a movement script. So I am puzzled as to why the two smaller bosses won't move.

```
public class BossHealthManager : MonoBehaviour {

public int enemyHealth;

public GameObject deathEffect;

public int pointsOnDeath;

public GameObject bossPrefab;

public float minSize;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (enemyHealth <= 0)
    {
        Instantiate(deathEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        ScoreManager.AddPoints(pointsOnDeath);

        if(transform.localScale.y > minSize)
        {
            GameObject clone1 = Instantiate(bossPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), transform.rotation) as GameObject;

            GameObject clone2 = Instantiate(bossPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z), transform.rotation) as GameObject;

            clone1.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.y * 0.5f, transform.localScale.y * 0.5f, transform.localScale.z);
            clone1.GetComponent<BossHealthManager>().enemyHealth = 10;

            clone2.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.y * 0.5f, transform.localScale.y * 0.5f, transform.localScale.z);
            clone2  .GetComponent<BossHealthManager>().enemyHealth = 10;
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }


}

public void giveDamage(int damageToGive)
{
    enemyHealth -= damageToGive;
    // play whatever audio attached to the gameobject
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
}
```

}

This is my movement script for my bosses:

```
public class BossPatrol : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed;
public bool moveRight;

// wall check
public Transform wallCheck;
public float wallCheckRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsWall;
private bool hittingWall;

// edge check
private bool notAtEdge;
public Transform edgeCheck;

private float ySize;

void Start()
{
    ySize = transform.localScale.y;
}

void Update()
{
    hittingWall = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(wallCheck.position, wallCheckRadius, whatIsWall);

    notAtEdge = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(edgeCheck.position, wallCheckRadius, whatIsWall);

    if (hittingWall || !notAtEdge)
    {
        moveRight = !moveRight;
        //Debug.Log("hit");
    }

    // moving right
    if (moveRight == true)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-ySize, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    }
    else if (moveRight == false)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(ySize, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    }
}
}
```

[Big Boss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdzMv.jpg)

[Smaller Bosses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIKnV.jpg)

Thanks for help!

Comment: please post your script for the movement of the bosses

Comment: @ryemoss Updated!

Comment: Oh i found the problem! I didnt un-check the is Kinematic option

Answer (score 0):

The user ended up solving his problem by unchecking the Kinematic option on the prefab's Rigidbody.

Quoting the comments:

> Oh i found the problem! I didnt un-check the is Kinematic option

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved the problem was choose the interpolate option on Rigidbody